# MysqlCommand ExecuteNonquery return value is always 0

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I've trying to validate when mysql executes a non query, it should return me the rows that have been affected. Yet, when I use a stored procedure, it always return me 0.

Note: This code is generic to execute any stored procedure and return the out values of the stored procedure if neccessary.

C# :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute the query to mysql DB and returns all the OUT values by the DB..
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strStoredProcedureName">Name of the stored procedure to execute</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">list that contains all the IN parameters name with their respectif values</param>
    /// <param name="outParameters">list that contains all the OUT parameters name with their My SQL DB types</param>
    /// <param name="lstOfOutValues">List that contains the OUT parameter name and the value that the DB returned.</param>
    /// <returns>True, executed successfully</returns>
    public static bool Execute(string strStoredProcedureName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, Dictionary<string, MySqlDbType> outParameters, out Dictionary<string, object> lstOfOutValues)
    {
        bool blnIsExecuted = true;
        MySqlCommand cmd = null;
        int rowsAffected = 0;
        Dictionary<string, object> lstOfValues = null;
        string strParameterName = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (dbMain = DB.OpenConnection())
            {
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(strStoredProcedureName, dbMain);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // IN paramters
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in parameters)
                {
                    strParameterName = string.Format("?{0}", item.Key);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(strParameterName, item.Value));
                    cmd.Parameters[strParameterName].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                }

                // OUT paramters
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MySqlDbType> item in outParameters)
                {
                    strParameterName = string.Format("?{0}", item.Key);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter(strParameterName, item.Value));
                    cmd.Parameters[strParameterName].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }

                rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Execute the query
                blnIsExecuted = rowsAffected > 0 ? true : false;

                if (blnIsExecuted)
                {
                    lstOfValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                    // Create the list of values from the out paramters array.
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, MySqlDbType> item in outParameters)
                    {
                        strParameterName = string.Format("?{0}", item.Key);
                        lstOfValues.Add(item.Key, cmd.Parameters[strParameterName].Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            blnIsExecuted = false;
            lstOfValues = null;
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Class : [DB]"
                                                         + "\nMethod : Execute(string strStoredProcedureName, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, Dictionary<string, MySqlDbType> outParameters, out Dictionary<string, object> lstOfOutValues)"
                                                         + "\n\nError : {0}", ex.Message), "ERROR");
        }

        lstOfOutValues = lstOfValues;
        return blnIsExecuted;
    }
```

The stored proc :

```
# DECLARATIONS OF VARIABLES
DECLARE Test TINYINT(1) DEFAULT false;
DECLARE varDocumentID INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE varFileName VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE varQuery LONGTEXT DEFAULT '';

# ROLLBACK if there's any SQL Exception or Warning error with the Insert of the Transactions
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
BEGIN
    SELECT false AS Result;
    ROLLBACK;
END;

SET varQuery = CONCAT('INSERT INTO order_document_reception'
                      , '\r', 'SET OrderType = \'', argOrderType, '\''
                      , '\r', ', Status = \'O\''
                      , '\r', ', Priority = ', argPriority
                      , '\r', ', ClientID = \'', argClientID, '\''
                      , '\r', ', BillingID = \'', argBillingID, '\''
                      , '\r', ', ShippingID = \'', argShippingID, '\''
                      , CASE WHEN argModelID != '' THEN CONCAT('\r', ', ModelID = \'', argModelID, '\'') ELSE '' END
                      , CASE WHEN argDiscountID != '' THEN CONCAT('\r', ', DiscountID = \'', argDiscountID, '\'') ELSE '' END
                      , '\r', ', PurchaseOrderNumber = \'', argPurchaseOrderNo, '\''
                      , '\r', ', DocumentFileName = \'', argOrderType, '\''
                      , '\r', ', DocumentReceivedDate = \'', argDocumentReceiveDate, '\''
                      , CASE WHEN argDocumentReceptionType != -1 THEN CONCAT('\r', ', DocumentReceptionType = ', argDocumentReceptionType) ELSE '' END
                      , '\r', ', DocumentReceivedBy = \'', argDocumentReceivedBy, '\''
                      , CASE WHEN argTherapist != '' THEN CONCAT('\r', ', Therapist = \'', argTherapist, '\'') ELSE '' END
                      , CASE WHEN argPurchaser != '' THEN CONCAT('\r', ', Purchaser = \'', argPurchaser, '\'') ELSE '' END
                      , CASE WHEN argUser != '' THEN CONCAT('\r', ', User = \'', argUser, '\'') ELSE '' END
                      , CASE WHEN argClientWO != '' THEN CONCAT('\r', ', ClientWorkOrderNumber = \'', argClientWO, '\'') ELSE '' END
                      , '\r', ', CreatedDate = \'', NOW(), '\'');
IF Test THEN
    SELECT varQuery;
ELSE
    START TRANSACTION;
        SET @Qry = varQuery;
        PREPARE Statement FROM @Qry;
        EXECUTE Statement;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE Statement;

        # FETCH THE LAST INSERT ID OF THE DOCUMENT TO CREATE THE FILE NAME.
        SET varDocumentID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        SET varFileName = CONCAT(argOrderType, '_', CONVERT(varDocumentID, CHAR(50)), '.pdf');

        # UPDATE THE DOCUMENT NAME
        UPDATE order_document_reception SET DocumentFileName = varFileName WHERE (ID = varDocumentID);

        # SET THE argDocumentID PARAMETER TO THE DOCUMENT ID VARIABLES THAT WAS USED TO CREATE THE ORDER DOCUMENT.
        SELECT varDocumentID INTO argDocumentID;
        SELECT varFileName INTO argFileName;
    COMMIT;

    SELECT true AS Result;
END IF;
```

I see that the insert has been done successfully when I select directly from Mysql but my rowsAffected variable is always 0, why ?

Answer (score 0):

I think because you have your Insert done indirectly as an executed String within the SP, vs in raw form.

I wrote a quick ST Test in the workbench.. one with an indirect call similar to what you have

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tester`()
BEGIN


DECLARE varQuery LONGTEXT DEFAULT '';

SET varQuery = CONCAT('INSERT INTO therinks.glreturndata '
                  , '\r', 'SET glaccount = \'', 'test', '\'');


 SET @Qry = varQuery;
    PREPARE Statement FROM @Qry;
    EXECUTE Statement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE Statement;


END
```

When run through the workbench.. it returns 0 rows effected .. even though it inserted

then i used a direct insert.. like such:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tester`()
BEGIN



INSERT INTO therinks.glreturndata SET glaccount = 'test';



END
```

When ran through the workbench .. it correctly reports back 1 row effected.

I would try a test and have the insert statement not hidden behind the String and see if that test returns the correct row count first.